# Add location pin and remove bubble from google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was wondering, how is one meant to get the "pin" in the location on google maps, and also remove the speech mark bubble that appears?

I have googled for "search mark" and "dialogue" box but it doesn't come up with anything, so I think I have the wrong name for it.

This is my current Google map (you have to type in a location for the map to show)

http://jsfiddle.net/2q8Pw/17/

Is this because I am using the "defaultUI: false option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now there is marker.setVisible(false) and it should read marker.setVisible(true) for the marker to appear

and get rid this to make the bubble not appear

`infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);`